# Compiling a Visual Studio Project using the UnityEngine

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I wondered if you could help.
I have with me an app project made for both IOS and Android. It comes with its normal .sln file in which I can open it up in VS. This solutions file contains 3 projects, I am not sure if one is for IOS and one is for Android. There seems to be one which holds all the c# files.

Unity was outdated so I referenced its libraries with undated version and replaced any deprecated functions with the new ones. Libraries include the UnityEngine, UnityEditor, UnityEditor.UI and so on.

All seems to be building successful with no errors.

Now by the looks of things this project never used the Unity Editor. There seems to be UNITYPROJ Files and the file structure seems to match Unity but no actual Project file. The Unityproj files wont open in Unity either.

[image]

[image]

From the looks of things I guess I am missing the Android SDK to compile to an android simulator or Xcode or IOS? Am I missing something obvious here to open it in Unity or I am missing a large portion of SDK's.

Thanks
Hayley

Comment: The Project files are usually in the Assets folder. Check again. Without it you are basically compiling nothing!

Comment: Its ok now, I just had to reference the file not actually search for a project file. All is fine.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.